# Remove element with duplicate property based on another property from list using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm struggling to reduce a list :

Let's say I have a `List<Item> listItems` with an `Item` class defined such as :

```
public class Item {
    private String effect;
    private String value;

    public String getEffect() {
        return effect;
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        this.effect = effect;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, in my `listItems` list, I have some elements with the same `effect` property.

I want to remove all element from my `listItems` list with the same `effect` property except the one with the higher `value` property. (`value` is number represented as a `String`).

Also, I wanna keep all the element with an unique `effect` property.

How can I achieve that ? I guess I'm gonna have to deal with `Comparator`.

Comment: Do you want to do it for a given `effect` or need to search for all duplicate `effect`s ?

Comment: all duplicate `effect` unfortunatly, My list needs to become `effect` unique.

Comment: One way is you can implement hashCode and equals method in Item class based on effect variable and then in just one line you can create a Set which will remove all duplicate Item based on effect and will have effect unique.

Comment: think of formulating these into `Map<String, Item>` where keySet would be your unique effects and their values would be the Item with the largest value corresponding to the effect.

Comment: can you override `equals` and `hashCode` for `Item`? if yes, based on both or a single property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to group the items of your list by `effect`, using `max(value)` as an aggregation. You can do this as follows:

```
Map<String, Item> byEffectHavingMaxValue = listItems.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Item::getEffect,      // group by effect
            Function.identity(),  // keep items as values
            BinaryOperator.maxBy( // when effect exists, keep the item with max value
                    Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i.getValue())))));

Collection<Item> result = byEffectHavingMaxValue.values();
```

The solution above collects elements of the stream to a `Map`. For this, it uses an overload of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) that requires 3 arguments:

- *keyMapper*: a `Function` that transforms elements of the stream to keys
- *valueMapper*: a `Function` that transforms elements of the stream to values
- *mergeFunction*: a `BinaryOperator` that is used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key

In this case, the `Item::getEffect` method reference is being used as the *keyMapper* function, which transforms an `Item` instance to its `effect`. Then, `Function.identity()` is being used as the *valueMapper* function, which does nothing, i.e. it leaves each `Item` instance untouched. Finally, `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i.getValue())))` is being used as the `mergeFunction`, which is a `BinaryOperator` that receives two values of the map that have the same key (i.e. two `Item` instances with the same `effect`), and resolves the collision in the map by selecting the `Item` instance that has the max `value` (`value` is first converted to `Integer`, so that we compare numeric values instead of strings).

Comment: the OP also needs elements that don't share other `effect` property, isn't it?

Comment: right, but this map will report `effect` that is present in two `Item`s. So if you have `ItemA{effect = 1, value = 2}; ItemB={effect=1, value=3}; ItemC={effect = 3, value = 10}` the OP needs two things, first is the result of your operation, second is `ItemC` only - as it's the only one in the `List` that does not share `effect` with anyone else - at least this is my understanding

Comment: This seems like the right way to achieve what I want.
Could you elaborate on the `toMap` parameters ?
From what I've read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) it's using effect as a key, the Int Comparator as a merging function, but I don't really get what does the "mapping function" `identity` do. Keeping item as values ? (Like an hascode ?)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. As explained by nullpointer, you could have a map with effect as key ,
   and item as value.  Please refer the code snippets below

Add elements to list like shown below

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
itemList.add(new Item("e1", "10"));
itemList.add(new Item("e1", "20"));
itemList.add(new Item("e1", "30"));
itemList.add(new Item("e2", "10"));
itemList.add(new Item("e3", "10"));
itemList.add(new Item("e3", "-10"));
```

Logic to eliminate duplicates and keep items with highest value

```
Map<String, Item> effectMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Item item : itemList) {
    Item itemWithHigherValue = effectMap.get(item.getEffect());
    if (itemWithHigherValue == null || 
        (Integer.parseInt(item.getValue()) > 
        Integer.parseInt(itemWithHigherValue.getValue()))) 
    {
        effectMap.put(item.getEffect(), item);
    }

        }
```

Printing the results

```
List<Item> uniqueItemList = new ArrayList<Item>(effectMap.values());

for (Item item : uniqueItemList) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"I wanna keep all the element with an unique effect property": assuming all `Item` objects have valid `effect` and `value` :

```
//group list entries to sub - lists having the same effect value
Map<String, List<Item>> map = itemList.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getEffect)) ;

List<Item> uniqueEfectMaxValue = new ArrayList<>();
//get item having max value and add to uniqueEfectMaxValue
map.forEach((key,list)->{
                          Item item = list.stream().
                             collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.
                                  comparing(Item::getValue))).get();
                          uniqueEfectMaxValue.add(item);
                         }
             );
```